# Preventing excel from messing up mac addresses

Tags: excel, windows, ms-office, mac-address

I'm working daily with excel at my job, and many times the data i'm viewing contains mac addresses and mac address prefixes. 
If the mac address contains only numbers (e.g: 12:34:56) excel automatically transform the number to a function, at the time of the opening (same example: 0.52425). there is no way to transform this number back to a mac address.
if the mac address starts with a zero and then more zeros, excel automatically deletes the first zero (e.g - 00:00:12 -> 0:00:12).

The only way i found so far to go around it is to open an empty worksheet - and pressing data - > Get data from CSV. it's annoying and time consuming.

do you have any idea how i can prevent excel from doing that on opening ?

Comment: Simply use "custom" as field

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to know for sure without a sample file to try, but normally when opening a CSV it offers you the 'Text Import Wizard'- step 3 has a field for 'Column Data Format', I'd have thought simply specifying 'text' here would resolve this.